# Get rid of white space on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

thanks for your help in advance. I'm an amateur, so this might be a dumb question.

I just put a form redirect code in a Wordpress page. For some reason, there is a big white space gap between where the effects of the code start and the top of the page. I can't seem to get rid of white space without breaking the form. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<br>` every line after `<!-- Start of form code -->` remove them in your editor. Right now result code looks like

```
<p>  <!-- Start of form code --><br>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script><br>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://wwweurope1.systemmonitor.eu.com/siteforms/fValidate.config.js"></script><br>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://wwweurope1.systemmonitor.eu.com/siteforms/fValidate.core.js"></script><br>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://wwweurope1.systemmonitor.eu.com/siteforms/fValidate.lang-enUS.js"></script><br>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://wwweurope1.systemmonitor.eu.com/siteforms/fValidate.validators.js"></script></p>
```

every `<br>` adds new empty line. Either try to configure TinyMCE Editor or remove line breaks manually

**UPD** [TinyMCE Advanced plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) is especially developed to solve such problems with TinyMCE filters. After installing it (you can also do it directly from `/wp-admin/plugin-install.php`), go to Settings > TinyMCE Advanced

Comment: there is also no reason to have a paragraph element to contain <script> tags.

Comment: Thanks vladkras. Had never heard of TINYMCE. Installed it and was able to fix the problem.